# Calling functions in a namespace from cshtml

Tags: typescript

I've found what seems like a total gotcha with Typescript and namespaces. If I put a Typescript function in a namespace and call that function in an onclick the call fails in IE, but works in Chrome and Firefox.

i.e. Typescript

```
namespace @idARPanelHdrWithHash
{
    export function ChangeText(id : string)
    {
    }
}
```

cshtml:

```
<p id="@idARPanelHdr"
   class="UserARViewMore collapsed"
   onclick="ChangeText('@idARPanelHdrWithHash')"
   data-toggle="collapse"
   data-target="@idARPanelWithHash">
   VIEW MORE
</p>
```

If I change onclick to "AdminEditPages.ChangeText('@idARPanelHdrWithHash') it works in IE but not in Firefox or Chrome.

If I open debug tools in IE, call up the console and enter AdminEditPages when I hit '.' I get all the type ahead stuff, but nothing in Chrome or Firefox. Clearly the namespace does not exist in Firefox or Chrome.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance,

## Adam Benson.

Comment: It probably has nothing to do with typescript but with this `cshtml` thing that you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the name you are using for the namespace is not a valid identifier name and the code won't compile to javascript.

Just lose the @.

```js
namespace idARPanelHdrWithHash
{
    export function ChangeText(id : string)
    {
    }
}
```

When it compiles you can see what the generated Javascript is.

```js
var idARPanelHdrWithHash;
(function (idARPanelHdrWithHash) {
    function ChangeText(id) {
    }
    idARPanelHdrWithHash.ChangeText = ChangeText;
})(idARPanelHdrWithHash || (idARPanelHdrWithHash = {}));
```

If that cshtml will eventually become html the correct way of calling the ChangeText function would be.

```html
<p id="@idARPanelHdr"
   class="UserARViewMore collapsed"
   onclick="idARPanelHdrWithHash.ChangeText('@idARPanelHdrWithHash')"
   data-toggle="collapse"
   data-target="@idARPanelWithHash">
   VIEW MORE
</p>
```

For quick reference you can use the TypeScript playground to see what TypeScript code compiles to. Like [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=namespace%20idARPanelHdrWithHash%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20function%20ChangeText(id%20%3A%20string)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D).

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, toskv. I apologise for the typo with the namespace - I think yesterday I'd stared at the problem that long that I'd gone a bit blind with it. Your reply reassured me of what to expect and so I cleaned out all my browser caches and tried again. This time it worked as exepected across IE, Chrome and Firefox. So prefixing the event handler with the namespace in the cshtml makes it work. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it does. when you can please also mark the answer as the corect one so other people will know that's the way to do it. :)

Comment: Done :-) For anyone's reference I've had a couple of "weirdies" with Visual Studio 2013 \ MVC this week where the browser appeared to be running the wrong code (which is what seemed to be behind this.) In one case I'd run up an earlier version of the software to check something, ran up the version I was working on and yet IIS Express served up the old version. Reboot fixed it.